# Using mixin from Bootstrap to custom in LESS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I want to over-ride `border-radius:20px` for my custom.less. Without repeatedly writing vendor fixes as below, is there any way to call an existing `mixin` from Bootstrap LESS files?

```
.borderRadius(@radius){
border-radius: @radius;
-moz-border-radius: @radius;
-webkit-border-radius: @radius;
}

div{
.borderRadius(20px);
}
```

Comment: Vendor prefixes haven't been required for `border-radius` in a long time (unless you want to support the pre-historic browsers :P). By the way, whats wrong with your current call?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap doesn't actually use `mixins` for vendor prefixes anymore, the prefixing is done with an [autoprefixer](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer).

However, if you want to use Bootstrap's other mixins, you can just import them

```
@import 'path/to/bootstrap/less/mixins/alerts.less`

.foo {
  .alert-variant(red, green, blue);
}
```

If you want to modify your border-radiuses, change or overwrite `@border-radius-base` in `path/to/bootstrap/less/variables.less`.